# Docker mongodb share volume with mac os x

Tags: mongodb, docker, boot2docker

I try to use the mongodb official docker image on mac os x 10.10.2 with this command inside mac terminal :

```
docker run -v /Users/john/data/db:/data/db -p 27017:27017 mongo --smallfiles
```

But it exits with this error log :

```
2015-04-11T10:53:19.709+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-04-11T10:53:19.711+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover begin
2015-04-11T10:53:19.711+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] In File::open(), ::open for '/data/db/journal/lsn' failed with errno:1 Operation not permitted
2015-04-11T10:53:19.711+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion failure f.is_open() src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/dur_journal.cpp 597
2015-04-11T10:53:19.713+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
0xf69069 0xf09861 0xeeed9e 0xd2b8f7 0xd36852 0xd37561 0xd37a90 0xd254b6 0xa9b9f9 0x824220 0x7f13c4 0x7f6dbae1bead 0x822459
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B69069"},{"b":"400000","o":"B09861"},{"b":"400000","o":"AEED9E"},{"b":"400000","o":"92B8F7"},{"b":"400000","o":"936852"},{"b":"400000","o":"937561"},{"b":"400000","o":"937A90"},{"b":"400000","o":"9254B6"},{"b":"400000","o":"69B9F9"},{"b":"400000","o":"424220"},{"b":"400000","o":"3F13C4"},{"b":"7F6DBADFD000","o":"1EEAD"},{"b":"400000","o":"422459"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.1", "gitVersion" : "534b5a3f9d10f00cd27737fbcd951032248b5952", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.18.5-tinycore64", "version" : "#1 SMP Sun Feb 1 06:02:30 UTC 2015", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "4AB5B4C24C9EE5C1743971702746CDB87DC92DCE" }, { "b" : "7FFFFE772000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C58213BB786BBA102C73C58D3FF0123C2006C7F4" }, { "b" : "7F6DBC38B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FEF281218797AD6AE726DD5FCEDECADD9E9F51DC" }, { "b" : "7F6DBC12B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AEE5F3A05E87AFA440FCF6352C568A0F08584119" }, { "b" : "7F6DBBD33000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "37084B8E55653C947BA6295814D850D6AA0C561D" }, { "b" : "7F6DBBB2B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F58D5DE3E7A2989E915422BA4203FE53DBA449A0" }, { "b" : "7F6DBB927000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D1CA3A3D93ED5B6C6462FFA03E787FDBE4013A3" }, { "b" : "7F6DBB620000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8711429397A5AF8B6269B867D830EDF6E0225B8D" }, { "b" : "7F6DBB39E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7F58D6664571941C86B2D969701A572AD4D7BF1D" }, { "b" : "7F6DBB188000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F980B1188708F8D8B5C35D185444AF4CB939AA1E" }, { "b" : "7F6DBADFD000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A745EBA2C16BA80AE1EF1A7A7B70740C2CF1B363" }, { "b" : "7F6DBC5A7000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9B23F2A44CC8CA6175CBD8D64584B1C7EA5FD18C" }, { "b" : "7F6DBABE6000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1EFEB71FD4999C2307570D673A724EA4E1D85267" } ] }}
mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x29) [0xf69069]
mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0xE1) [0xf09861]
mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0xCE) [0xeeed9e]
mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur14journalReadLSNEv+0x1E7) [0xd2b8f7]
mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur11RecoveryJob2goERSt6vectorIN5boost11filesystem34pathESaIS5_EE+0xB2) [0xd36852]
mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur8_recoverEv+0x851) [0xd37561]
mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur27replayJournalFilesAtStartupEv+0x60) [0xd37a90]
mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur7startupEv+0x26) [0xd254b6]
mongod(_ZN5mongo23GlobalEnvironmentMongoD22setGlobalStorageEngineERKSs+0x319) [0xa9b9f9]
mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x2F0) [0x824220]
mongod(main+0x134) [0x7f13c4]
libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xFD) [0x7f6dbae1bead]
mongod(+0x422459) [0x822459]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 F JOURNAL  [initandlisten] dbexception during recovery: 13611 can't read lsn file in journal directory : assertion src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/dur_journal.cpp:597
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13611 can't read lsn file in journal directory : assertion src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/dur_journal.cpp:597, terminating
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-04-11T10:53:19.716+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

What i don't understand is that if i execute this same command inside docker-machine, with the same data placed inside a docker-machine folder then everything works fine.

I already tried to chmod -R 777 on the folder but it doesn't fix the problem.

Can someone explain what i am doing wrong here ?

Can we place data inside the "/Users" folder mounted in docker-machine to share with containers on mac os x ?

Is mongodb requiring something specific about the filesystem ?

Comment: Are you using boot2docker?

Comment: Yes docker-machine is the new boot2docker

Comment: Might be silly but are you in docker users group or have you tried using sudo? Looks like a permissions error

Comment: You might want to have a look at the OSX sections of https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mwmahlberg/m202docker/

Comment: Thank for the link but in fact i already did all this.

Comment: @MartinH-Works: I doubt that, since you are trying to mount an OS X directory into an docker image, which simply does not work. You need a data image (the `busybox` image) and make it accessible to the MongoDB image.

Comment: I try to mount an OS X directory inside a docker container but "/Users" is mounted automatically inside docker-machine (boot2docker) so "/Users/john/data/db" is also in the docker host.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be specific to the mongo software and the use of virtualbox , see the mongo docker [README](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mongo/).

> WARNING (Windows & OS X): The default Docker setup on Windows and OS X uses a VirtualBox VM to host the Docker daemon. Unfortunately, the mechanism VirtualBox uses to share folders between the host system and the Docker container is not compatible with the memory mapped files used by MongoDB (see [vbox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819), [docs.mongodb.org](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories) and related [jira.mongodb.org bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8600)). This means that it is not possible to run a MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host.

It doesn't behave like that if you keep the datadir out of the mounted volume.

Comment: Could you clarify this? What do you mean keep the datadir out of the mounted volume? In order to write from it it would have to be mounted wouldn't it? Do you mean on a separate slice from the one the image is running from?

Comment: Same problem with elasticsearch official container. Container is unusable.

Comment: Maybe now dinghy - relying on nfs instead of vboxfs - for macosx is solving this issue https://github.com/codekitchen/dinghy

Comment: I suppose he means that the host machine volume directory cannot be under /Users (or ~) try to mount it e.g. at /usr/local/mongodb

Answer (score 7):

Running on the [docker osx native beta](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/) (which uses [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) rather than VirtualBox), it's now possible to mount the mongo data directory to the host system properly and without issue.

**My setup**: MacBook Pro with El Capitan, Docker native beta Version 1.11.1-beta10 (build: 6662), Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:27017:27017 -v ~/foo/data/db/:/data/db --name foo-mongo mongo
7f8a72ec42b0ac235f49e0edd8d4f6613b45d10beb54012ca643629218a6653d

docker logs foo-mongo
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=7f8a72ec42b0
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.4
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian71
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-05-05T23:42:54.014+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-05-05T23:42:54.028+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-05-05T23:42:54.560+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-05-05T23:42:54.560+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-05-05T23:42:54.560+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-05-05T23:42:54.560+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-05-05T23:42:54.560+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-05-05T23:42:54.560+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-05-05T23:42:54.560+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2016-05-05T23:42:54.562+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2016-05-05T23:42:54.562+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-05-05T23:42:54.573+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

ls ~/foo/data/db/
WiredTiger       WiredTiger.turtle  WiredTigerLAS.wt  collection-0-516089495343762760.wt  index-1-516089495343762760.wt  mongod.lock    storage.bson
WiredTiger.lock  WiredTiger.wt      _mdb_catalog.wt   diagnostic.data/                    journal/                       sizeStorer.wt
```

Comment: @devalias it's not working for me with docker for mac beta, do I need to config something?

Comment: @Ravan I didn't have to config/do anything special. I've updated above with the docker command I used and mongo log output.

Comment: But can another container share access to the shared volume/bind mount?  I'm getting errors when trying to share access.