# Can not add a volume to Mongodb Docker instance

Tags: macos, mongodb, docker

I just installed Docker and I am using the official MongoDB repository.

To keep things simple, I am using Kitematic (the point and click tool for docker).

Mongo works ok, but when I try to add a volume for the data the image does not start
`docker run --name mongo-volume -v /Users/iosif/development/mongoDB/db:/data/db -d mongo:latest`

I get this error in the log:

`2015-11-10T12:54:02.654+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-11-10T12:54:02.654+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100`

The folder that I am trying to link has 777 permision rights.
I tried with an empty folder and a folder which already contained data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker mongodb share volume with mac os x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570989/docker-mongodb-share-volume-with-mac-os-x)